# How to use aframe-react events properly in .map?

Tags: aframe, aframe-react

I'm trying to render images and each images should be clickable. I tried to write a code below. However, the **click events** fires when a user access to the component. Can you explain why is it happening?

[the code that I wrote is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5Lcj.png)

Answer (score 1):

When I use a callback function, it worked out!

*events={{click: () => this.props.addToCart(item.product_id)}}*